# Upload image file without being on base 64

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to upload an image that goes to a folder on my server. So I need to upload the image file, where it can not be on base 64. I'm trying with File Transfer however it returns error 1 and the file path gets as 'unsafe: C: \ fakepath'.

Code that uploads the file, is in error:

```
AnexoUpload() {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'ionicfile',
      fileName: 'ionicfile',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
      headers: {},
      params: {
        'contemArq': 'S',
        'id': this.IdAnexo,
        'fileAnexo': this.file
        // the rest of your form fields go here, except photo
      }
    };

    fileTransfer.upload(this.img, 'http://localhost:61473/api/v1/cadastros/despesa/anexo', options)
      .then((data) => {
        this.retornoMsg(data);
      }, (err) => {
        this.retornoErro(err);
      });
  }

  fileEvent(e){ // Change of input type file
    this.file = e.target.files[0];
  }
```

View:

```
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]="ImgArq" (change)=fileEvent($event)/>
```

Comment: Maybe you could decode the base64 on your api endpoint and then save it as a file on your server ?